# TouchID for Android using IBM Mobile First Platform 7.1 and Ionic

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-cli, mobilefirst-studio

Am trying to integrate Touch Id for Hybrid Application, i have done with the iPhone(working) and now am stuck with android application.
Here is my query How can i achieve the Touch id integration with Android,

these are the sample links i tried to integrate,
https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-android-fingerprint-auth
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/worklightsmobileplayground/entry/touchid_authentication_with_worklight?lang=en

Any idea how to proceed further.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest trying the sample application that is referenced in the documentation here: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/t_setting_up_touch_id_jsonstore.html

It's not a complete project, but can be added to an existing Hybrid or iOS native application.  Please give it a try and let us know if you have difficulties with with.

Comment: hi john,   ios is working fine! can you suggest Touchid for android with IBM Mobile first